# Flutter UI override

Tags: flutter, dart

I am following a series and using the method to create different style of app in flutter but stuck with a page ui override. Below is the main code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class BasePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const BasePage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  BasePageState createState() => BasePageState();
}

class BasePageState<T extends BasePage> extends State<T> {
  bool isApiCallProcess = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(70.0), child: _buildAppBAr()),
      body: ProgressHUD(
        inAsyncCall: isApiCallProcess,
        opacity: 0.3,
        child: pageUI() ?? SizedBox.shrink(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget? pageUI() {
  return null;
}

Widget _buildAppBAr() {
  return AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    elevation: 0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[800],
    automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
    title: const Text(
      'Welcome',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
    ),
    actions: const [
      Icon(
        Icons.notifications_none,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 10,
      ),
      Icon(
        Icons.shopping_cart,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 10,
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

I want to override the child of the scaffold which is `pageUI()` but it's returning the Sizedbox instead.
the code for the override page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'base_page.dart';

class ProductPage extends BasePage {
  const ProductPage({Key? key, required this.catgeoryId}) : super(key: key);

  final int catgeoryId;

  @override
  _ProductPageState createState() => _ProductPageState();
}

class _ProductPageState extends BasePageState<ProductPage> {
  @override
  Widget pageUI() {
    return Text(
      widget.catgeoryId.toString(),
    );
  }
}
```

Flutter underlines the `pageUI()` in this code *The method doesn't override an inherited method.
Try updating this class to match the superclass, or removing the override annotation.* Any assistance will be appreciated.

tried  below code and others but no result

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(70.0), child: _buildAppBAr()),
      body: ProgressHUD(
        inAsyncCall: isApiCallProcess,
        opacity: 0.3,
        child: Container(child: pageUI(),) ,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'base_page.dart';

class ProductPage extends BasePage {
  const ProductPage({Key? key, required this.catgeoryId}) : super(key: key);

  final int catgeoryId;

  @override
  _ProductPageState createState() => _ProductPageState();
}

class _ProductPageState extends BasePageState<ProductPage> {
  @override
  Widget pageUI() {
    return Text(
      widget.catgeoryId.toString(),
    );
  }
}
```

To this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'base_page.dart';

class ProductPage extends BasePage {
  const ProductPage({Key? key, required this.catgeoryId}) : super(key: key);

  final int catgeoryId;

  @override
  _ProductPageState createState() => _ProductPageState();
}

class _ProductPageState extends BasePageState<ProductPage> {
  @override
  Widget? pageUI() {
    return Text(
      widget.catgeoryId.toString(),
    );
  }
}
```

The return type must properly match with the Base return type.

Comment: Still returning blank white screen

Comment: Check the logs. Might be you got some parent widget rendering wrong.

Comment: yes, did some code check from yesterday and got it fixed. Appreciated